# How is a Karhunen-Loeve decomposition different from a generalized Fourier series?

Tags: stochastic-processes, approximation-theory

The Karhunen-Loeve decomposition takes an $L^2$-integrable stochastic process $X_t$ and decomposes it into a series of deterministic processes $e_i(t)$ that form a basis of $L^2$, multiplied by random variable "coefficients" $Z_i$, where these coefficients are determined by an inner product-like integral $Z_i = \int_a^b X_t e_i(t)dt$.

This looks fairly obviously like a generalized Fourier series, with the stochastic processes forming a Hilbert space, but with two key differences:

1. The basis elements are *specific* types of elements in the (possible) Hilbert space, rather than just any set of stochastic processes that form a basis in $L^2$.
2. The "coefficients" in this case are random variables rather than scalars, which would only create a correspondence between the K-L decomposition and generalized Fourier series if the underlying vector space of stochastic processes had random variables as its scalar elements.

**Are these differences explained simply by non-intuitive methods in the way the underlying vector space of stochastic processes is constructed, or is the K-L decomposition a similar but truly different construction to a generalized Fourier series?**

Comment: Yes it is the same as a Fourier series, except that the basis depends on the stochastic process (not on its realization). You should start from a process $X(t)=\sum_k C_k e^{2i\pi kt}$ where the $C_k$ are uncorrelated random variables (but not independent) and see what it means for $\Bbb{E}[X(t)\overline{X(t+a)}]$. Then Karhunen–Loève says any process whose covariance doesn't depend on $t$ decomposes this way, and that it works for any  process $Y(t)$ once we know the linear operator $X(t)=L[Y(t)]$ such that $\Bbb{E}[X(t)\overline{X(t+a)}]$ doesn't depend on $t$.

Comment: Does that mean that the underlying vector space formed by such stochastic processes uses random variables as its scalar elements? (I’m more than happy to confirm your comments as an answer.)

Answer (score 1):

You should look first at the finite dimensional case.

Let $v$ be any $\Bbb{R}^n$-valued random variable with finite mean and variance.  Let $\mu= \Bbb{E}[v]$ and $w=v-\mu$. The covariance matrix $$R_{ij} = \Bbb{E}[w_i w_j]$$ Then $R$ is real symmetric [thus it diagonalizes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theorem#Finite-dimensional_case) into an orthonormal basis $$R^\top = R \implies R = P D P^\top$$
(where $P$ is a real orthonormal matrix and $D$ is a real diagonal matrix)

Moreover $$a^\top R a= \Bbb{E}[(\sum_{i=1}^n a_i w_i)^2]\ge 0 \implies D_{ii}\ge 0$$
Let $$u = P^\top w,\qquad \Bbb{E}[u u^\top]=\Bbb{E}[P^\top u u^\top P]= D_{ij}$$
Whence $$v = \mu+P u$$ 
where $u$ is a $\Bbb{R}^n$-valued random variable whose components are pairwise non-correlated.

If a process $X$ can be well-approximated by some finite dimensional random variables then this kind of decomposition extends to $X$.